# Ошибка в поиске слов

Tags: c

Дан файл, содержащий текст на русском языке. Найти слова, встречающиеся в каждом предложении, или сообщить, что таких слов нет.

Работает так. Если это первое слово в предложение и оно во всех повторяется то выводит. А если это не первое слово то не работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    //Русский язык
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    const int LEN = 1000;
    char s[LEN];
    char a[LEN / 10][LEN];              // в каждой строке хранится соот-щее предложение
    char d[LEN];

     char array[1000];
     FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
     while( fscanf(file, "%79[^\n]\n", array) == 1 ) {
        printf("%s\n", array);
    }

    strcpy(s, array);

    fflush(stdin);

    int n = -1;                         // общее количество предложений в строке
    char *p = strtok(s, ".");           // разделитель между лексемой "точка", т е высекаем предложения
    if(p)                               // чтобы убедиться, что во входном тексте имеется хотя бы ОДНО предложение
    {
        n++;
        strcpy(a[n], p);
    }
    do
    {
        p = strtok(NULL, ".");
        if(p)
        {
            n++;
            strcpy(a[n], p);
        }
    }
    while(p);

    // поскольку нужно найти слова в каждое предложении, поступим очень просто. Разобъем ПЕРВОЕ предложение на слова и проверим
    // каждое слово с каждым словом в других предложениях. Если текущее слово не встретиться в остальных предложениях, значит оно
    // не подходит и переходим к следующему слову
    char q[100];
    strcpy(q, a[0]);
    p = strtok(q, " ");// указываем, что разделитель между словами ПРОБЕЛ (a[0] - первое предложение во входном тексте)

    bool b, glob;                           // будет равна
    char tmp[LEN], tmp1[LEN];
    char *p1;
    bool yn = false;
    if(p)
        strcpy(tmp, p);

    while(p) {

        // пробегаем по всему массиву предложений кроме первого
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            glob = true;
            b = false;                      // предположим что текущего слова из ПЕРВОГО предложения НЕТ в остальных предложениях
            strcpy(d, a[i]);
            p1 = strtok(d, " ");

            if(p1)
            {
                strcpy(tmp1, p1);
                if(strcmp(tmp, tmp1) == 0)
                    b = true;
            }
            while(p1)
            {
                p1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
                if(p1)
                {
                    strcpy(tmp1, p1);
                    if(strcmp(tmp1, tmp) == 0)
                        b = true;
                }
            }
            if(b == false)
            {
                glob = false;
                break;              // нет смысла проверять в других предложениях, т к в i - ом анализируемого слова не обнаружено
            }

            free(d);
        }
        if(glob) {
            printf("%s\t", tmp);
            yn = true;

        }
          p = strtok(NULL, " ");

        if(p)
            strcpy(tmp, p);

    }
    if(!yn){
        printf("\n\nСлова не были обнаружены");
    }

    if(p != NULL)
        free(p);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Обнаружил странную работу.   `p = strtok(NULL, " ");`  не выводит дальше строки. Когда использую в цикле это. Он как-то буфер очищает? Потому что если я тело оставлю пустое, я получу все свои слова.

`strcpy(d, a[i]);
   p1 = strtok(d, " ");`

Comment: Мне кажется, второй вариант не работает, из-за условие который вызывает break.

Comment: сам текст кириллицой написан или латиницой?

Comment: пока латиницей.

Comment: Все задачи подобного типа решаются одинаково, а именно выбором hash-функции (например, CRC32; можно так же разбить все слова на списки списков, где первый уровень по первой букве, второй по второй, третий по третьей, а дальше просто список) и построением дерева для поиска. А то, что у вас русский язык на входе, только добавляет радости с кодировками и прочими интересностями юникода. Удачи!

Comment: Если чесно, в ваш код совсем не хочется смотреть, а вот каркас для решения "в лоб" есть: https://pastebin.com/vsQG1bPS

Comment: Я подправил код, и догадываюсь в чем дело. И всё же я не знаю как исправить.  p = strtok(NULL, " ");  выводим нулевое значение, то есть буфер где-то теряется. Хотя в цикле я нигде не ссылаюсь на него больше

Comment: Посмотрите в мой код. И не используйте `strtok()` вообще. Устаревший API, полный граблей.

Comment: strtok иногда полн сюрпризов, и потоко не безопасный, правда в вашем случае это не имеет значения. Попробуйте начать цикл с strsep, для разделения на строки, внутри ещё один аналогичный цикл с разбиение на слова. Примерчик: `while ((line = strsep(&source, ".")) != NULL) {...}`

Comment: Про strtok, он использует внутренней статичный буфер, по этому использование его в одном участке кода с разными переменными может давать разные эффекты. Если есть желание или необходимость использовать именно strtok, то используйте лучше [strtok_r](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/).